# Create tabs in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I wanna create tabs in my jquery mobile application like this one:

[image: url]

[image: look and feel]

The functionality is like this, i think:
http://jsfiddle.net/m8wQM/

```
        <div data-role="content">   
            <div data-role="navbar" id="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active" data-tab-class="tab1">Tab1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-tab-class="tab2">Tab2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-tab-class="tab3">Tab3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-tab-class="tab4">Tab4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab1">
                    Tab1
                </div>
                <div class="tab2 ui-screen-hidden">
                    Tab2
                </div>
                <div class="tab3 ui-screen-hidden">
                    Tab3
                </div>
                <div class="tab4 ui-screen-hidden">
                    Tab4
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /content -->
```

How i get the look and feel, like on this page?

Comment: You can simply edit the `li`'s with css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use your own css, just get it [here](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php), and you can edit it. Don't use external link as I saw on your jsfiddle. It'll give default 'jquery-mobile' style.